# Nested Sets и отметка записи в нескольких категориях одновременно

Tags: mysql

Не секрет что клиентам все чаще мало просто древовидного представления данных. Все чаще начинают просить чтобы запись выводилась в нескольких категориях одновременно. Но создание связующей таблицы  даст возможности получить записи только в том случае если мы запрашиваем только прямых потомков. А что если нам нужны записи которые выше и выше?

Если кто-то обладает информацией как этот вопрос решается прошу просветить.

```
CREATE TABLE srv1.al_page(
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
  id_parent INT(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID Parent',
  level_obj INT(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The nesting level',
  left_key INT(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Left key  (Nested Sets)',
  right_key INT(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Right key  (Nested Sets)',
  obj_type TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Type (node/loop)',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX FK_al_page_al_page_properties_group_id (id_group),
  INDEX UK_al_page (left_key, right_key, id_parent, level_obj),
  INDEX UK_al_page_url (url, sign_lang, linking)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1241
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 248
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT = REDUNDANT;
```

Comment: Запросами все это легко выбирается. Дополните свой вопрос структурой таблиц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если дерево хранится по алгоритму Nested Sets то, выборка всех вышестоящих веток будет

```
SELECT *
FROM table_tree
WHERE (ind_left < [ind_left текущего узла]) AND (ind_right > [ind_right текущего узла])
ORDER BY ind_right
```

Сортировка от ближайшего родителя до корня дерева.

**UPD:** Чтобы отметка могла касаться сразу нескольких разных узлов дерева нужны 3-и таблицы. 1-я дерево; 2-я отметки; 3-я связующая, а ней два поля ID узла в дереве из 1-й и ID отметки из 2-й.

**UPD2:** Что-то типа:

```
SELECT *
FROM al_page t1 -- дерево
INNER JOIN table_3 t3 ON t3.id_node = t1.id
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.id = t3.id_mark
WHERE (t1.left_key >= @left_key) AND (t1.right_key <= @right_key )
```

На выходе все записи соответствующие выбранной ветке дерева и всем в нее вложенным.

`t1`, `t2`, `t3` - алиасы трех таблиц предложенных выше. `id_node` и `id_mark` предполагаемые названия полей в таблице для связки таблиц дерева и меток. `@left_key` и `@right_key` левая и права границы выбранной ветки.

Comment: Ну я не о том. Это понятно я такой запрос с разбуди меня в 2 часа ночи, напишу. Меня инетерсует именно проблема размещения (отметки) документа в нескольких узлах одновременно. Это как правило в магазинах такое практикуют.

Comment: Дополнил ответ

Comment: Думал об этом. Есть на прототипе у меня таблица 3. Как она поможет вытянуть мне записи если я запрошу ветку на два уровня ниже? Вот собственно в чем я и не разобрался.

Comment: Дополнил ответ